# JavaScript Grid copy as String

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

I am having little problem on JavaScript. What I am doing is copying data from a grid and pasting into another. I was able to access the value from the cell, but problem comes as I try to format those value to string.
my code:

```
var colseperator = '~';
var rowseperator = '    ';

var clipStr = "";
if(selecttype = "area")
{
    for (var i = startrow; i <= endrow; i++) 
    {
        for (var j = startcol; j <= endcol; j++)
        {
            var cellValue = objGrid.getCellValue(i,j);
            if(this.gfn_isNull(cellValue))
            {
                cellValue = "Null";
            }
            clipStr = clipStr + cellValue;
            if(j != endcol)
            {
                clipStr = clipStr + colseperator;
            }
        }
        if(i != endrow)
        {
            clipStr = clipStr + rowseperator;
        }
    }
}
```

From code above, my intention is copy the data into string format and separate each data with separator(in my case '~' for columns and 'indent' for rows). However, when I select one column(multi rows) and copy it, it would add column separators to all the rows.
I was thinking that `if(j != endcol){clipStr = clipStr + colseperator;}` would stop it from adding unnecessary separator. Am I doing something wrong here? And any tips on iterating the selected grid cells or formatting string?

**example:**
When I select those three lines,

| row | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |

Output:

```
a~  b~  c~
```

My expected output:

```
a   b   c
```

Comment: do you have some data to work with? what is the result you want and what do you get?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a variable for a cols and add the separator if not iteratng the first item.

```
var colseperator = '~',
    rowseperator = '    ',
    clipStr = "";

if (selecttype = "area") {
    for (var i = startrow; i <= endrow; i++) {
        var cols = "";
        for (var j = startcol; j <= endcol; j++) {
            var cellValue = objGrid.getCellValue(i, j);
            if (this.gfn_isNull(cellValue)) cellValue = "Null";
            if (j !== startcol) cols += colseperator;
            cols += cellValue;
        }
        if (j !== startcol) clipStr += rowseperator;
        clipStr += cols;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it fixed the problem. I was using wrong operators for whole time.